# "Close method of Workbook class failed": Is anyone else getting this error recently?

Tags: excel, vba

After a recent batch of Windows Updates my application gets this error:

*Close method of Workbook class failed*

The easiest way to demonstrate it is:

1. Create a new Excel file.
2. Create a new macro and paste in these lines:

```
Dim workbook As Object
Set workbook = CreateObject("Excel.Sheet")
workbook.Close
```

3. Run the macro.

On a computer that has the recent updates I get the error. On a computer that doesn't have the updates it works.

**Questions:**

- Has anyone else noticed this?
- Which specific Windows Update triggers this?
- Is Microsoft aware of this and/or doing anything about it?
- Does anyone know any solutions or work-arounds?

Comment: Clarification: The problem originally occurred in a legacy VB6 application that I maintain and support.I know it's old technology but replacing it will take a long time. For now, Microsoft has an official policy that VB6 should still work on Windows 10.

Comment: It looks like a more recent Windows Update has resolved this. As of May 13 my old code works again without any changes. The test environment started failing with a Windows Update in early April, and started working again with a later update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>That example never worked, it would consistently throw "ActiveX can't create object", because you simply cannot create an `Excel.Sheet` object - Excel firstly does not even define any `Sheet` class, and second..</s> *edit: *I stand corrected, there **is** an `Excel.Sheet` ProdID registry key and `CreateObject("Excel.Sheet")` seems to "work", but my experiments ended with Excel going up in flames, wouldn't recommend*.

`Worksheet` objects (normally?) live in a `Sheets` object collection that is owned by a `Workbook` object, itself living in a `Workbooks` object collection, that is owned & operated by an `Application` object - and *that* is a class you can create with `CreateObject` - to create a `Workbook` object, you need to use the object model's `Workbooks` collection class (i.e. a workbook cannot exist up in the air, it needs to be a child object of a parent collection of workbooks that is itself owned by an `Application` object):

```
With CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    With .Workbooks.Add
        '...
        .Close
    End With

    .Quit

End With
```

However if your code is hosted in Excel, the Excel library is already referenced: using `CreateObject` to get a type the compiler already knows how to resolve, is a lot of work for nothing (why go lookup a ProgID string in the registry when the type you're looking for is *literally right there*). Avoid coding against `Object` when you have compile-time access to the types involved.

When you're in Excel and need to create a new `Excel.Application` object, a much more direct way to do it is with the `New` keyword:

```
With New Excel.Application

    With .Workbooks.Add
        '...
        .Close
    End With

    .Quit

End With
```

Comment: Thank you. I tested your example and confirmed that it works. Please note that my code has worked for many years but started failing only recently. Requesting an "Excel.Sheet" object used to work, and oddly the object returned by Excel was a Workbook object. The challenge with creating an Application object is that I want it to be in the background and I don't want my code to close Excel if the user had other files open. But I'll take your advice and be careful to address those other issues.

Comment: Setting `Visible = False` on your `Excel.Application` object should hide it. There never was any `Sheet` class in the Excel object model though, that code couldn't have possibly ever worked anywhere.

Comment: "Excel.Sheet" is a Class in the registy:[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet\CurVer]
@="Excel.Sheet.12"
If you use CreateObject("Excel.Sheet")  you get an Excel.Workbook object. Try it and you'll see.

Comment: When I originally wrote my code 12 years ago I was working with Excel 2003 or 2007 and creating an Application object caused Excel to immediately appear in the foreground, and there were issues that hiding it and/or closing it affected other files that the user might have open. But none of that happens with the latest version of Excel, so your code is good. :)

Comment: @DenisTerBerg well I'll be damned, the key exists, ...and `CreateObject("Excel.Sheet")` "works" (although my session ended up crashing)... interesting that `CurVer` points to Excel 12, i.e. 2007. Learned something new today, thanks! (edited my answer)